# Ubuntu uses external DNS to resolve localhost

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I have Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.13. 
It can take 1sec to run "dig localhost" when computer is connected to Internet.
When it is disconnected it is much faster.
I checked /etc/hosts, I tried disabling dnsmasq in Network manager. Nothing helps.
Applications that call localhost, just stop for a fraction of a second until Ubuntu goes to resolve localhost to remote servers.
I search everywhere and did not find a solution.
Can someone help me with this ?

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40343
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;localhost.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
localhost.      10800   IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 359 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Feb  7 23:02:10 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43

Comment: You say that you checked `/etc/hosts`, was `localhost` there?  Also, `dig` uses DNS rather than the system resolver library, meaning that it will not use hosts and is not particularly suited for testing what a normal application will do.

Comment: My /etc/hosts: 127.0.0.1 localhost 127.0.1.1 donald  plus the usual IPv6 stuff. ping localhost is 0.03ms. I noticed the problem the first time when I was debugging Linphone. It takes unusually long for Linphone to register on the same machine. It takes hundreds of miliseconds, while it should be 1ms.

Comment: `ping` will not actually tell you how long it took to resolve the name, though? What does for instance `time getent ahosts localhost` say?

Comment: `127.0.0.1       STREAM localhost
127.0.0.1       DGRAM  
127.0.0.1       RAW    
127.0.0.1       STREAM 
127.0.0.1       DGRAM  
127.0.0.1       RAW    

real 0m0.002s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s`